# How to make a div with a blinking cursor and editable text without using <input>?

Tags: javascript, css, html, input

I need to make a div layer so that when you click on it you will have your cursor there blinking and you can insert/delete text just like `<input type="text">` does, except that I do not want to use it as it is slightly too limited to my case.

I can definitely use JavaScript.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DIV element has (other elements as well) `contentEditable` property that you can set in Javascript to true.

```
getElementById('YourDiv').contentEditable = true;
```

Comment: Can be done in markup as well: <div contentEditable="true">Editable content</div>

Comment: Ok, I thought it was only possible on the document, sorry !

Comment: Note that 'contentEditable' is not in the HTML4.01 specification, or in the DOM2 HTML specification (1.0). It is something added by browsers.

Comment: It does, however, appear in the HTML5 **draft**: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable

Comment: That is kind of cool, but I really just need a working JavaScript/CSS solution that allows me to add text into DIV's InnerHTML.

Answer (score 5):

You can make the div editable by setting its `contentEditable` attribute / property to `true`. However, for anything that is slightly more powerful or flexible then very basic editing, you might want to look at existing solutions such as:

- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)
- [Kevin Roth's RTE](http://kevinroth.com/rte/)
- [The YUI editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)

Answer (score 2):

Jquery can be used like this:

```
$.('#yourDiv').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a textarea, and if that's not enough, use a WYSIWYG editor like tinyMCE or FCKeditor.

Answer (score 0):

**contenteditable** attribute could be used for this purpose. Following code line has been tested in IE7 and Firefox 3.0.10. One part, I have noticed that this attribute should be used in lower case only; else it wont work in Firefox.

```
<div id="Div_ID" contenteditable="true" tabindex="0">
   Enter text here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as I understand your problem, you can resove it by adding `textarea` into your `div`. It is very simply to make this `textarea` autosize to occupy whole `div` area and looks like this `div`.

As for `contentEditable`, I have seen some browsers, supported this feature for `div`-element and does not. Anyway, you can use `iframe` in your div. It's `document`-element can have `contentEditable`.