# HTML5 ContentEditable not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am building a HTML5 webapp and I tried using contenteditable feature to make a in-place edit of text,but for some reason I couldn't get "editing" to work.

EDIT: I am using Chrome 12.0.xx

- It highlights the Element(I can see it by CSS)
- I also tested `object.isContentEditable` which returns `true`
- I tried changing `<lable>` to other elements like `<div>`,`<p>`,`<span>` nothing works.Only `<textarea>` works but I am guessing that has got nothing to do with HTML5 or contenteditable attribute.
- `blur` event gets fired on exit of edit mode.(I can see from debugger)

With some clue in question [How do I figure out why the contenteditable attribute doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534692/how-do-i-figure-out-why-the-contenteditable-attribute-doesnt-work) I tried turning off of all CSS but no luck.

The only thing is, I am adding my elements via javascript rather that HTML source

**JS Code:**

```
var newLi =document.createElement("li");
var newLable=document.createElement("lable");
newLable.className="labletext";
newLable.contentEditable="true";
newLable.innerText=String(localStorage["task."+i+".taskValue"]);
newLable.addEventListener('blur',editTask,false);
newLi.appendChild(newLable);
Parent.appendChild(newLi);

function editTask()
{
   var keyid=this.id;
   var startchar = keyid.lastIndexOf("_");
   var endchar=keyid.length;        
   var taskId=parseInt(keyid.substring(startchar+1,endchar));

   localStorage.setItem("task."+taskId+".taskValue",this.innerText);
   loadTasks("tasklist");
}
```

Comment: You don't need to supply the second argument to `substring` if you want to go to the end of the string. Just  `keyid.substring(startchar+1)` is good.

Comment: You know that `addEventListener` doesn't work in IE8, right?

Comment: You know that `innerText` doesn't work in Firefox, right?

Comment: Hi,thanks for letting me know.I changed code.Also,I am focusing on making this app for chrome, so IE8 is not issue for me right now.I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's

```
document.createElement('label')
```

not `'lable'`

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XuAfA/1/

The demo shows that the LABEL *is* editable.

Comment: Hi,I just tried this and in chrome it doesn't work.Even blur event doesn't get fired.with Lable atleast highlight happens and blur event gets fired. I also tired same in IE9 and both label and lable works fine and content is editable.

Comment: I checked your demo and its fine in chrome.I must be doing something wrong.I will look at things again.thanks for your help

Comment: Found the issue.I also enable draggable attribute on <li> hence click event is hijacked <li> before reaching <lable>.  Its answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954994/how-can-i-enable-draggable-on-a-element-with-contenteditable

Comment: Found the issue.I also enabled draggable attribute on <li> hence click event is hijacked by <li>(I use jquery) before reaching <lable>.  Its answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954994/how-can-i-enable-draggable-on-a-element-with-contenteditable

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming later here,I Found the issue.I also enabled draggable attribute on `<li>` hence click event is hijacked by `<li>` events before reaching `<label>` child.  Its answered here [How can I enable 'draggable' on a element with contentEditable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954994/how-can-i-enable-draggable-on-a-element-with-contenteditable).