# jQuery draggable cancel option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am studying jQuery draggable cancel option, but I am not getting any example to understand the 'cancel option'.

Can I get an example?

Comment: What do you mean by *"cancel option"*? Are you talking about http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-cancel?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/EPKfR/ . It let you specify `elements` inside the `draggable set` where dragging cant be started.

Comment: @Vision yes I am talking about that link.

Comment: @user1476794 There are many variants where `cancel` option is useful. Please have a look at the examples in the answer below.

Comment: You should accept VisioN answer. He has presented examples and info as you requested

Answer (score 7):

From the [jQuery UI docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-cancel) `cancel` option ...

> ... prevents dragging from starting on specified elements.

Lets have a look at the following example.

*HTML:*

```
​<div class="selector">This can be dragged</div>
​<span class="selector">​​​​​​​This can be dragged</span>
<input type="button" value="This can be dragged" class="selector" />
<button class="selector">This can't be dragged</​​​​​​​​​​​​​​button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$(".selector").draggable({
    cancel: "button"
});​
```

Here `button` element has `selector` class and should be dragged as the other elements with the same class. However, `cancel` option is set for all `button`, so all `button` elements with class `selector` are excluded from the draggable list and can't be dragged.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/uPRaH/

---

In the next example we have many `li` elements with `selector` class which can be dragged.

```
<ul>
    <li class="selector">This can be dragged</li>
    <li class="selector">This can be dragged</li>
    <li class="selector not-this">This can't be dragged</li>
    <li class="selector">This can be dragged</li>
    <li class="selector">This can be dragged</li>
    <li class="selector">This can be dragged</li>
    <li class="selector">This can be dragged</li>
</ul>​
```

Let's exclude the third element with class `not-this` from the draggable list. It is also easy to do with `cancel` option:

```
$(".selector").draggable({
    cancel: ".not-this"
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/uPRaH/1/

---

In the third example we can see how `cancel` option is useful to prevent dragging by nested elements.

For the following markup...

```
<div class="selector">
    Draggable
    <div>Draggable</div>
    <span>Not draggable</span>
    <div>Draggable</div>
    Draggable
</div>
```

... let's make so that we can drag `selector` by any handle except `span`:

```
$(".selector").draggable({
    cancel: "span"
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/uPRaH/2/

Answer (score 0):

This sample program may helps you. To test this, Please drag the list items and drop them in textarea. You can get to know the functionality.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                #divFields
                {
                    margin-right: 2em;
                }
                #txtMessageFields
                {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 1em 0 1em 3em;
                    font-weight:bold;
                    font-size:18px;

                }
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">        
                $(document).ready(initialize);
                function initialize() 
                {
                    $("#divFields li").draggable
                    ({
                        helper: "clone",
                        cancel:"li#iComputer"
                    });


                    $("#divDroppedFields").droppable
                    ({
                        accept: "#divFields li",                            
                        drop: function (event, ui)
                        {                               
                                $(this).find('#txtMessageFields').append((ui.draggable.attr('data-value')));                        
                        }
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="divFields">
                <ul>
                    <li data-value="iPhone">iPhone</li>
                    <li data-value="iPod">iPod</li>
                    <li data-value="iComputer" id="iComputer">iComputer</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="divDroppedFields" class="ui-widget-content">
                <textarea id="txtMessageFields" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```