# Dragging input text in jQuery UI draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ec2T1unVjOQOwWmADrGo?p=preview) I have a div that contains an input field readonly. I made the div draggable with jQuery UI.

When I drag the portion that is not hidden by the input field, it works fine (try dragging the orange area). But when I try to drag the div by dragging the input field, the div doesn't move. I need to drag the div even though the mouse is on any element included in the div. Is this possible?

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var div1 = $('#div1');
    div1.draggable();
    var input1 = $('<input type="text" readonly value="Some Text" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;border:0">');
    input1.appendTo(div1);   
})
```

Comment: add div1.draggable(); after input1.appendTo(div1);   and check

Comment: can you please create fiddle as i am not able to open link provided by you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```
$(function() {
    var div1 = $('#div1');
    var input1 = $('<input type="text" readonly value="Some Text" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;border:0">');
    input1.appendTo(div1);   
    $('#div1').draggable({
                cancel: ''
    });
});
```

> Basically what `cancel` option does is it will cancel dragging options
>   on those elements mentioned inside it. Since you do not want to cancel
>   drag option on any child elements, just leave it blank.

You can find more information in **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169701/jquery-draggable-cancel-option)** and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756771/draggable-and-clickable-input-element-using-jquery)** link and
Here is the **[Working Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SFVJtzdNY2Z93V9CSpa6?p=preview)** for your reference

Comment: Thanks, this worked, however sometimes I need the input field to be enabled, I tried to remove `readonly` in your plunk but the field stays disabled. Any idea why?

Comment: I made it work, [this is the plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/s8JqHW6Tsfo11e1lSOmQ?p=preview)

Comment: @pgschr.. Sorry!! I just saw your response. Glad it worked. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Nice work @GuruprasadRao and @pgschr! You guys resolved my problem, that edit text trick was very nice to serve both drag and edit purposes. Thanks :)

Comment: @AnmolSaraf Gald it helped you too.. happy coding.. :)