# show blink text cursor on html document

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, jwysiwyg

I am writing my own WYSIWYG html editor based on jquery.
In order to achieve this goal, I am exploring jWYSIWYG. I've figured out that I need usual html container(e.g div) in order to show formatted text.And I need to bind all events(keydown, mouseclick) for applying changes on this container.
There is another problem: How to show blink text cursor. I can't realized how this implemented in jWYSIWYG. There is a simple iframe with html document. How they show blink text cursor???

Comment: Set [contentEditable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to true for the div. That's the core essence of what makes the fancy wysiwyg editors work.

Comment: I hope you know what you are getting into with this - `contentEditable` probably has an incredibly complicated set of quirks that need to be worked around. The editor I have written has over 3000 lines of code, and most of that is correcting browser quirks. It doesn't even have list or table support.

Comment: @takayoshi: Why did you delete [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905379/wpf-datagrid-return-key-problem) after I solved your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at     `contentEditable property;`

```
getElementById('YourDiv').contentEditable = true;
```

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?p=74576#post74576

There are many similar questions here:

[How to make a div with a blinking cursor and editable text without using <input>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882256/how-to-make-a-div-with-a-blinking-cursor-and-editable-text-without-using-input)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799445/create-a-blinking-cursor